# Unable to access properties of a DOM element

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Inside a AlpineJS init function, I'm accessing a DOM element by ID. This element is static, loaded inside a Blade template. I can `console.log` the element and see all the properties, including `clientWidth` (value = 161). But when I try `console.log(container.clientWidth)`, the value is 0. Strangely, I can access some properties but not all of them (offsetWidth, offsetTop, all 0).

Here is some samples of my code:

```
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('booking', () => ({
            bookings: [],
            init: function() {
                let container = document.getElementById('slot-'+bookings[i]['resource_id']);
                console.log(container); // Returns the full properties
                console.log(container.clientWidth); // Returns 0

[...]
```

Extract of container properties inside the console:

```
[...]
className: "inline-block mr-3 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100 h-3 border-t"
clientHeight: 11
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 1
clientWidth: 161
[...]
offsetHeight: 12
offsetLeft: 185
offsetParent: div.p-3.w-full.border-y.relative
offsetTop: 141
offsetWidth: 161
[...]
```

If I run a `console.log(container.className)` instead, I get the correct value.
I really don't get it.

If you have any idea, that'd be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: In the `init` function it can be zero. Try to embed it into [`$nextTick()`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/nextTick), like `this.$nextTick(console.log(container.clientWidth))` so Alpine.js waits until DOM updating is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my mistake, for some reason, I added an [x-cloak] attribute on the  tag. Therefore, it was breaking my code.
Thanks anyways